# Bacula Storage error

Tags: bacula

Need some help, with bacula.
I delete all volumes at pool and delete file of pool from host (Vol--). Also delete jobs from Job list. Delete by BAT.
To avoid mistakes create a new pool and storage.
After that all running jobs, get errors:
Error:
bacula0-dir Created new Volume="BacPool-0036", Pool="File_pool_for_bacula0", MediaType="FileXX" in catalog.
bacula0-sd Warning: mount.c:215 Open of File device "DISK1" (/backup/DISK1) Volume "BacPool-0036" failed: ERR=file_dev.c:190 Could not open(/backup/DISK1/BacPool-0036,OPEN_READ_WRITE,0640): ERR=No such file or directory
Marking Volume "BacPool-0036" in Error in Catalog.

After that error create a new pool, new label but have the same error.

What i need to do for clean remove Storage and Pool?

***bacula-dir.conf***

```
Director {                                                          # Bacula0-dir
  Name = bacula0-dir
  DIRport = 9101
  QueryFile = "/usr/local/share/bacula/query.sql"
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/db/bacula"
  PidDirectory = "/var/run"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 2
  Password = "console-pass"                                         # Console password in dir.conf
  Messages = Daemon
  DirAddress = 10.7.0.141
}

Catalog {                           # Generic catalog service
  Name = MyCatalog
  dbname = "bacula"; dbuser = "bacula"; dbpassword = "m@cter"
  DB Address = 10.7.0.141
}

Messages {                      # Reasonable message delivery -- send most everything to email address  and to the console
  Name = Standard

  mailcommand = "/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -h localhost -f \"\(Bacula\) \\" -s \"Bacula: %t %e of %c %l\" %r"
  operatorcommand = "/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -h localhost -f \"\(Bacula\) \\" -s \"Bacula: Intervention needed for %j\" %r"
  mail = root@localhost = all, !skipped
  operator = root@localhost = mount
  console = all, !skipped, !saved

  append = "/var/log/bacula.log" = all, !skipped
  catalog = all
}

Messages {                          # Message delivery for daemon messages (no job).
  Name = Daemon
  mailcommand = "/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -h localhost -f \"\(Bacula\) \\" -s \"Bacula daemon message\" %r"
  mail = root@localhost = all, !skipped
  console = all, !skipped, !saved
  append = "/var/log/bacula.log" = all, !skipped
}
Console {                                   # Restricted console used by tray-monitor to get the status of the director
  Name = bacula0-mon
  Password = "console-pass"
  CommandACL = status, .status
}
```

***backup_job.conf***

```
Job {                                                               # Backup the catalog database (after the nightly save)
 Name = "Configfiles_bacula0"
 Type = Backup
 Client = bacula0-fd
 Storage = bacula0_storage
 Messages = Standart
 Pool = File_pool
 Level = Full
 FileSet="Configfile set"
 Schedule = "WeeklyCycle"
 Write Bootstrap = "/var/db/bacula/%n.bsr"
 Priority = 11                   # run after main backup
}

Job {                                                               # Only one such job is needed for all Jobs/Clients/Storage ...
  Name = "Restore_configfiles_bacula0"
  Type = Restore
  Client=bacula0-fd
  Storage = bacula0-storage
  # The FileSet and Pool directives are not used by Restore Jobs but must not be removed
  FileSet="Configfile Set"
  Pool = File_pool
  Messages = Standard
  Where = /backup/Restore/
}

Storage {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Name = bacula0-storage                                                                                           
Address = 10.7.0.141                # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here                                                                                                                                                                   SDPort = 9103                                                                                                       
Password = "device-pass"                                                                                             
Device = DISK1                                                                                                       
Media Type = FileX                                                                                                   
        }
```

***bacula-sd.conf***

```
Storage {                               # definition of bacula0-SD
  Name = bacula0-sd
  SDPort = 9103                         # Director's port
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/db/bacula"
  Pid Directory = "/var/run"
  Plugin Directory = "/usr/local/lib"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 2
}
                                        # List Directors who are permitted to contact Storage daemon
Director {                              #Local Director
  Name = bacula0-dir
  Password = "device-pass"
}                           
Director {                              # Restricted Monitor Director 
  Name = bacula0-mon
  Password = "tB2PEOFsM2C2FBrXfJziqOvsCHO87pD0r085/0aHlZaR"
  Monitor = yes
}

Device {                                #Device DISK0
  Name = DISK1
  Media Type = FileXX
  Archive Device = /backup/DISK1                    #dirrectory to save
  LabelMedia = yes;                                 # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;                             # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 2
}

Messages {                              # Send all messages to the Director,
  Name = Standard
  director = bacula0-dir = all
}
```

[BAT - Volumes [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Jig.png)

Answer (score 0):

You deleted all volumes, which means, your installation isn't worth resurrecting. That'll be the mere waste of time.

Save job, fileset and client configurations, and do a fresh Bacula install.